# Replace string values in lists

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list :

```
s = ["sam1", "s'am2", "29"]
```

I want to replace `'` from the whole list.
I need output as

```
s = ["sam1", "sam2", "30"]
```

currently I am iterating through the list.
Is there any better way to achieve it?

Comment: All answers for this question will ultimately be iterating over the list somehow unless!

Comment: What's the problem with iterating over the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this:

```
  s = [i.replace("'", "") for i in s]
```

but as pointed out this is still iterating through the list. I can't think of any solution that wouldn't include some sort of iteration (explicit or *implicit*) of the list at some point.

If you have a lot of data you want to do this to and are concerned about speed, you could evaluate the various approaches by timing them and pick the one that's the fastest, otherwise I would stick with the solution you consider most readable.

Comment: This is iterating over the list..he is asking for something else in his question.

Comment: Levon yes ultimately that will be the case even at a very atomic level

Comment: @dc5553 I agree with both of your comments

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `map` and `lambda`:

`map(lambda a: a.replace("\'",""),s)`

Answer (score 1):

Sam,

This is the closest way I can think of to do it without iteration. Ultimately it is iterating in some fashion at a very atomic level.

```
s = ["sam1", "s'am2", "29"]
x = ','.join(s).replace("'","").split(",")
```

Comment: I 100% agree but crazy question gets crazy answer, feel free to post a solution that doesn't involve iteration..

Comment: It could be adapted to use some other crazy seperator on the join, this is just an example of course